# React js Project Giving error on console?

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3zWe.png)
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/public ENOSPC
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher. (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher. (/home/rohan/myReactApp/hello/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app-01@0.1.0 start: `set port=3002 && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app-01@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rohan/.npm/_logs/2019-04-09T04_35_25_269Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be related to [this bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3254). The problem probably is that you don't have enough space on your disk and need to clean it up.